# Image of $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\}$ under the map $T$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let, $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that,
    $$\phi(n)=\begin{cases}
 \frac{n}{2} \text{  when n is even}
 \\
 3n+1 \text{  when n is odd}
 \end{cases}$$

Let, $M=\{A\in P(\mathbb{N}):\operatorname{card}(A)\geq 3\}$. Define, $T:M\rightarrow M$ by,
    $$T(A)=\{\phi(a):a\in A\}$$
    Let, $B=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\}$ for a fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then clearly $B\in M$.    Now my question is :

> Is there any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ for which, $T(B)=\mathbb{N}$?

Here, $P(\mathbb{N})$ is the power set of natural numbers.

Comment: Your definition of $T$ is not a map $M\to M$ (which is more a problem of your definition of $M$): With $A=\{1,2,8\}\in M$, you have $T(A)=\{1,4\}\notin M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Take $n=1$. Then $B=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ and $T(B)=\mathbb N$ because, if $n\in\mathbb N$, then $2n\in B$ and $\phi(2n)=n$.